# Ubuntu 18.04 The Network Connection could not establish the connection

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0JRbD.png)

I have installed OracleSQLdeveloper. And I got this error while creating a new connection.
Note : A lot of solution for this error is available for **windows** on the internet. I have tried them, but they do not work.

Comment: Did you actually install Oracle XE database on your machine?

Comment: I followed these instructions. https://aykutakin.wordpress.com/2017/07/22/installation-of-oracle-sql-developer-to-ubuntu/

Answer (score 0):

You have SQL Developer, but you don't have a database to actually connect to.

SQL Developer is the CLIENT - it's only a text editor and data modeling solution until you give it a database to work with.

I talk more about this here
 [I installed SQL Developer, now what?](https://medium.com/oracledevs/i-installed-oracle-sql-developer-now-what-71230b9c9303)